# Sort another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

How do I sort another worksheet where the last row and last column are unknown? I have worked on the following code, which is not working unfortunately.

```
Sub sample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Workbooks("x.xlsx").Sheets(1)

With ws

    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
    rng.Sort key1:=Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
         '
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: you forgot the `.` on `Range("A1")` in the key1. `rng.Sort key1:=.Range("A1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo`

Comment: It does not work with that change though

Comment: You will need to be more specific on `Does not Work`.  What does not work?  Do you get errors?

Comment: No errors, but it does not sort the sheet.

Comment: May be it's *already* sorted?

Comment: You need to understand that `Key1:=.Range("A1")` is a cell which is _relative_ to `rng`. It's just coincidence that `A1` cell happens to be the first cell of your range. You need to write one of the variants: `rng.Range("A1")`, `rng.Cells(1)` or `rng(1)` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lRow, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
```

In this case your range is only one line because both arguments in `.Cells` are `lRow`. If your header is in the first row, then it should be:

```
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))
```